# Gender Detection for Nouns in Spanish

Tags: nlp, part-of-speech

I am implementing a search engine in Spanish. In order to ensure gender neutrality, I need to get the gender of nouns in Spanish - e.g. "pintora" (painter, female) and "pintor" (painter, male). I am currently using [FAIR library](https://huggingface.co/flair/ner-spanish-large) - that it is really great for NER in Spanish. However, I cannot find any good implementation/library for gender detection in Spanish nouns. Could you help me?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using multiple search engines, including academic ones to perhaps try and find research papers covering topics pertaining to *Spanish word gender detection* and other related terms, there seems to be no one that has tackled the problem and implemented a solution in a modern library.

Regardless, you can still tackle the problem by running a Spanish Part of Speech (PoS) tagger (for example, [RuPERTa-base (Spanish RoBERTa) + POS](https://huggingface.co/mrm8488/RuPERTa-base-finetuned-pos)) to detect nouns/pronouns, combine those labels with your NER output where required, and then write your own rules for determining the gender of particular nouns/pronouns based on Spanish grammar rules (such as those detailed in [A New Reference Grammar of Modern Spanish](https://doi.org/10.4324/9781315648446), specifically [Chapter 1](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/mono/10.4324/9781315648446-1/gender-nouns-john-butt-carmen-benjamin-antonia-moreira-rodr%C3%ADguez?context=ubx&refId=9e494cba-d5f8-40f3-96b6-c2951de6352a)  *Gender of nouns*).

Hopefully that helps give you some direction if you don't end up finding a ready-made implementation.